# Undisplayed view crash in cocos2D

Tags: ios, console, cocos2d-iphone

There are no errors or warning but this crashes when I try and switch to the view:

```
#import "Level1.h"
#import "LevelSelect.h"
#import "GameOver.h"



enum {

kTagPlayer, kTagComputer
};



@implementation Level1



+(id) scene {

CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

Level1 *layer = [Level1 node];

[scene addChild: layer];

return scene;
}

-(id) init {
if( (self=[super init] )) {

CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon_Small_50.png"];
player.position = ccp(60, 60);
[self addChild:player z:2 tag:kTagPlayer];

CCSprite *computer = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon_Small.png"];
computer.position = ccp(440, 160);
[self addChild:computer z:1 tag:kTagComputer];



[computer runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0
                                        position:ccp(player.position.x,   player.position.y)]];



self.isTouchEnabled = YES;



[self schedule:@selector(SpritesDidColide) 
      interval:.01];

}
return self;
}



-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point];

CCNode *player = [self getChildByTag:kTagPlayer];
[player setPosition:point];

CCNode *computer = [self getChildByTag:kTagComputer];
[computer runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0
                                    position:ccp(player.position.x, player.position.y)]];


}
-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point];

CCNode *player = [self getChildByTag:kTagPlayer];
[player setPosition:point];

CCNode *computer = [self getChildByTag:kTagComputer];
[computer runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0
                                    position:ccp(player.position.x, player.position.y)]];

}



-(void) SpritesDidCollide {

CCNode *player = [self getChildByTag:kTagPlayer];
CCNode *computer = [self getChildByTag:kTagComputer];

float xDif = computer.position.x - player.position.x;
float yDif = computer.position.y - player.position.y;
float distance = sqrt(xDif * xDif + yDif * yDif);

if (distance < 45) {
[self unschedule:@selector(SpritesDidCollide)];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionScene transitionWithDuration:1        scene:[GameOver node]]];
}

}



@end
```

And here is what displays in the Console:

*** Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:], /Users/GLaDOS/Documents/Xcode 4 Projects/2DPlatformer/2DPlatformer/libs/cocos2d/CCScheduler.m:110
2012-02-17 19:13:07.460 2DPlatformer[709:707]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt'
** First throw call stack:
(0x37f1d8bf 0x31a031e5 0x37f1d7b9 0x31e1c3b3 0x46565 0x4843f 0x3402d 0x948d3 0x32249 0x93a23 0x37f20814 0x37e7b7e1 0x2de31 0x2bdc9 0x37e77435 0x7087f 0x71019 0x727ff 0x352ef50f 0x352eef01 0x352d54ed 0x352d4d2d 0x379f2df3 0x37ef1553 0x37ef14f5 0x37ef0343 0x37e734dd 0x37e733a5 0x379f1fcd 0x35303743 0x912c7 0x2300)
terminate called throwing an exceptionkill
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
quit
Program ended with exit code: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the schedule method will trigger a call back to a selector of the form:

```
-(void) SpritesDidCollide:(ccTime) dt{
    //  do your thing here. 
}
```

and change the selector to

```
[self schedule:@selector(SpritesDidCollide:) interval:.01];
```

Comment: I did both of those things, my app still crashes in the same spot, and the error is exactly the same...

Comment: Sorry Aaron, i retyped your typo, have now fixed the answer. Your method is SpritesDidColide should be SpritesDidCollide

Comment: Oh, wow. I would have never caught that. Thanks for your time.